# How to display all the tasks in Task scheduler

Tags: c++, windows, com, msdn, taskscheduler

I want to display all the tasks under **Task Scheduler** using the **COM library**.

I tried using the programs on learn.microsoft.com which uses the COM objects.
But instead of displaying all the 60 tasks, it displays only 12 tasks

```
//Get the pointer to the root task folder.
ITaskFolder *pRootFolder = NULL;
hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(L"\\"), &pRootFolder);

pService->Release();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Cannot get Root Folder pointer: %x", hr);
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

//  -------------------------------------------------------
//  Get the registered tasks in the folder.
IRegisteredTaskCollection* pTaskCollection = NULL;
hr = pRootFolder->GetTasks(NULL, &pTaskCollection);

pRootFolder->Release();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Cannot get the registered tasks.: %x", hr);
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

LONG numTasks = 0;
hr = pTaskCollection->get_Count(&numTasks);


TASK_STATE taskState;

for (LONG i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
{
    IRegisteredTask* pRegisteredTask = NULL;
hr = pTaskCollection->get_Item(_variant_t(i + 1), &pRegisteredTask);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BSTR taskName = NULL;
        hr = pRegisteredTask->get_Name(&taskName);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            printf("\nTask Name: %S", taskName);
            SysFreeString(taskName);

            hr = pRegisteredTask->get_State(&taskState);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                printf("\n\tState: %d", taskState);
```

I expected the output to display all the tasks, but it displays only a selected number of tasks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/displaying-task-names-and-state--c---

This is the link I used for the program

Comment: Could that be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue? How do you compile? Also does the program has enough rights to read the tasks?

Comment: @SimonMourier  My code is written in Visual Studio (x64). I've run Visual Studio as administrator. It still shows me 12 tasks.

Comment: I displayed the hidden tasks as well, now I get 18 tasks. Total number of tasks are 60

Comment: The tasks retrieved from get_Tasks (with hidden or not) will correspond to the user running the code. If you run as a normal user you will only see the tasks for that user. If you run with full privileges you shall see also the tasks that run as SYSTEM. Apart from that, there are also tasks in other folders.

Comment: @SimonMourier Visual studio is running as Administrator with full privileges. The tasks which are in the subfolders of system32\tasks aren't shown on the screen.

Comment: Forget about Visual studio, is your application .exe running as admin? Also, I'm not talking about physical drive folders, but scheduler folders (when you do GetFolder('\') you only read the root folder). The ones you see when you run the Task Scheduler application ("Task Scheduler Library", "Apple", "Microsoft", etc.).

Comment: @SimonMourier  There are over 13 subfolders in the Microsoft folder itself. Is it possible to iterate over those subfolders without hardcoding their paths?

Comment: Just use ITaskFolder::GetFolders

Comment: @SimonMourier I did, but I have to give it the path of the subfolders myself. Is it possible that it would iterate through the subfolders by itself?

Comment: Just do a recursive search from the root folder and so on

Comment: @SimonMourier How do I do that?

Comment: rootFolder::GetFolders will get all the subfolders in the root folder.

Comment: @SimonMourier  Could you implement it in the code above as I'm not able to figure out how to do the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample console app code that will display all tasks recursively, but as I said in the comment, the output will depend if you run this as admin or not.

```
// include task scheduler lib from code
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")

// some useful macros
#define WIDEN2(x) L ## x
#define WIDEN(x) WIDEN2(x)
#define __WFILE__ WIDEN(__FILE__)
#define HRCHECK(__expr) {hr=(__expr);if(FAILED(hr)){wprintf(L"FAILURE 0x%08X (%i)\n\tline: %u file: '%s'\n\texpr: '" WIDEN(#__expr) L"'\n",hr, hr, __LINE__,__WFILE__);goto cleanup;}}
#define RELEASE(__p) {if(__p!=nullptr){__p->Release();__p=nullptr;}}
#define STARTUP HRESULT hr=S_OK;
#define CLEANUP {cleanup:return hr;}

// forward declaration
HRESULT DumpFolder(ITaskFolder *fld);

int main()
{
  STARTUP;

  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    CComPtr<ITaskService> svc;
    CComPtr<ITaskFolder> fld;
    HRCHECK(svc.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler));
    HRCHECK(svc->Connect(CComVariant(), CComVariant(), CComVariant(), CComVariant()));
    HRCHECK(svc->GetFolder(CComBSTR(L"\\"), &fld));
    HRCHECK(DumpFolder(fld));
  }

  CoUninitialize();
  CLEANUP;
}

HRESULT DumpFolder(ITaskFolder *fld)
{
  STARTUP;
  CComPtr<IRegisteredTaskCollection> tasks;
  CComPtr<ITaskFolderCollection> children;
  LONG count;

  HRCHECK(fld->GetTasks(TASK_ENUM_HIDDEN, &tasks));
  HRCHECK(tasks->get_Count(&count));

  // dump out tasks
  for (LONG i = 1; i < (count + 1); i++)
  {
    CComPtr<IRegisteredTask> task;
    CComBSTR name;
    HRCHECK(tasks->get_Item(CComVariant(i), &task));
    HRCHECK(task->get_Name(&name));
    wprintf(L"name:'%s'\n", name.m_str);
  }

  // dump out sub folder
  HRCHECK(fld->GetFolders(0, &children));
  HRCHECK(children->get_Count(&count));

  for (LONG i = 1; i < (count + 1); i++)
  {
    CComPtr<ITaskFolder> child;
    HRCHECK(children->get_Item(CComVariant(i), &child));

    // go recursive
    HRCHECK(DumpFolder(child));
  }

  CLEANUP;
}
```