# enumerate all tasks in task scheduler

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to list all the Scheduled Task in Windows Task Scheduler. I read some documentation and tried some same codes from MSDN. This one for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/displaying-task-names-and-state--c---

The output is only the tasks specified in each Folder in Task Scheduler but I was trying to get everything in all the Folders.

Similar to the output of `Get-ScheduledTask` in powershell but in C++ using Windows Apis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample you tried just display the name and state of all the tasks in the root task folder.

```
hr = pService->GetFolder( _bstr_t( L"\\") , &pRootFolder );
```

When you call GetFolder, you only read the root folder. If you want to get everything in all the Folders, you could try to use [ITaskFolder::GetFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskfolder-getfolders) to get all the subfolders in the folder. And then you could do a recursive search from the root folder and so on.

I suggest you could refer to the thread: [How to display all the tasks in Task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571074/how-to-display-all-the-tasks-in-task-scheduler)

Comment: I came across that example, the code compiles fine but doesn't return any result not matter I run it as normal cmd or elevated one. I dont know enough of these objects to fix the issue.
Have you tried the code yourself?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you, and I have modified my reply.  Please check it.